# bash - directories ending in . and whitespace cannot be removed

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, filenames

On my external hard drive are two directories, `Fun.` and `Complex_`, where that _ is a whitespace.  I cannot empty from my trash or remove them with `rm -rf` and I want to.
Neither show up in Finder on OSX, and I don't remember if they showed up in dolphin on linux.  But they do show up in bash.

`rm` and `mv` returns `No such file or directory`.  Containing folders can be moved and bring the special directories with them but they cannot be deleted.

Why can `ls` detect the files but `rm` and `mv` can't?  How can I fix them?  I am using `\_`on the complex file. (_ is whitespace).

#### Edit

The characters must not be the problem. I made "test." and "test " and I had no trouble removing them using quotes.  But these dirs still cannot be removed.  There must be something very low level wrong with the actual files themselves

```
sagan:Math ptwales$ ls
Complex 
sagan:Math ptwales$ ls -i
ls: Complex : No such file or directory
sagan:Math ptwales$ ls -idF *
ls: Complex : No such file or directory
sagan:Math ptwales$ find . -name * -print0
find: ./Complex : No such file or directory
sagan:Math ptwales$
```

Same results with `Fun.`  I'm guessing that the parent dir's have links to the files and know their names but files just don't exist or are corrupted somehow.

The external drive is in exFAT format.  Would that be relevant?

Comment: This looks like a corrupted filesystem or a buggy filesystem implementation. You tagged the question `osx`, `linux` and `unix`. On which systems did you try to access the files? Were the results different? Did you try to access the files on Windows with exFAT support (see my partial answer)?

Comment: I created the files on linux on an ext4 partition then backed them up onto the exFAT.  I remember I had this problem deleting it on the ext4 system, but I can't check for sure.  The files aren't there now because I've repartition that drive since.  Right now it's being accessed from OSX.  I can try from a friend's windows setup, or boot from a debian thumb drive but the liveISO might not have exFat support installed.

Comment: *"The external drive is in exFAT format. Would that be relevant?"* I would say it definitely can be, as the FAT family of file systems treats file names very differently from the file systems normally used on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 5):

rm and mv can also detect the directories just fine, but it you type: `rm file` then the shell will ignore the whitespace.

There are a few things you can do to work around this. The easiest is to encapsulate the filename in quotes. Another solution is to escape the special char, e.g. with a backslash

Example:

```
touch "testfile "

host:/home/username/test>ls -al
total 12
drwx------   2 hennes  users  4096 Sep 26 02:44 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 hennes  users  8192 Sep 26 01:39 ..
-rw-------   1 hennes  users     0 Sep 26 02:44 testfile
```

Now to delete them, either:

`rm "testfile "`, or

`rm testfile\` (please notice the whitespace after the backslash)

---

As for filenames ending in a dot. I can not reproduce the problem. Are you sure it ends in a dot and not in some other special char?

```
toad:/home/hennes/test>bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.10(1)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd7.3)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

toad:/home/hennes/test>touch Fun.

toad:/home/hennes/test>ls
Fun.

toad:/home/hennes/test>rm Fun.
toad:/home/hennes/test>ls
toad:/home/hennes/test>
```

---

If it is another char than a dot then read up on the [Internal file separator](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/using-the-bash-ifs-variable-to-make-for-loops-split-with-non-whitespace-characters/) in bash. You can set it to something else, or just use commands sunch as find with -print0. (Example `find /path/to/search-name  'SomeFilePattern*'  -print0 | some_command`)

Comment: This works with other testing directories but not those.  The trailing characters must not be the issue here.

Comment: Does `ls -B` show anything?  ( -B      Force printing of non-printable characters (as defined by
             ctype(3) and current locale settings) in file names as \xxx,
             where xxx is the numeric value of the character in octal.
)

Comment: `ls -B "Complex "` and `Fun.` both turn up no such file or directory. I moving towards that there must be some exFAT file corruption maybe caused by the filenames but the file names aren't the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up an answer about this to [a rather similar question](https://serverfault.com/q/537749/58408) on Server Fault. The premise is slightly different but largely the same answer works.

You can combine `ls -i` (or `stat` which also prints the inode number) and `find -inum`. This works well for a small number of files, where for some reason direct wildcard globbing is undesired. The below example is adapted to directories, whereas the answer on Server Fault deals with files, but the principle is the same: using the inode number to identify the directory entry to do something with.

For example:

```
~$ ls -idF myweirddir
183435818 myweirddir/
~$ find . -inum 183435818 -exec mv -v '{}' 'delete-me' ';'
`./myweirddir' -> `./delete-me'
~$ ls -lA delete-me/
... check the contents ...
~$ rm -rf delete-me
~$
```

[This answer is also over on Server Fault, with minor differences and an alternative variant with direct process substitution using find and stat which probably isn't really applicable in your situation.](https://serverfault.com/a/537791/58408) If you like the answer here, consider upvoting on Server Fault as well.

Comment: I can't get the inode number of the files.  Perhaps the files actually don't exist and the problem is with the parent directory thinking they do?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a corrupted filesystem or a buggy filesystem implementation.

Unfortunately the [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) filesystem is poorly supported on non-Microsoft systems. If you have ability to use a different filesystem, please consider it.

Please check the filesystem integrity. On Linux you can check the exFAT integrity by running `exfatfsck`. Unfortunately this utility will not be able to repair the filesystem. On Windows (XP with update KB955704, Vista SP1 or newer) you can use `chkdsk` which is able both to check and repair the filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

When there is a file with some weird name that you can't type in, you can use bash select feature:

```
select f in * .*; do rm -i $f; done
```

Comment: If you don't quote `$f`, that's not going to work with all sorts of file names.

Comment: **(1)** This will ask about every file in the directory, which may or may not be what the OP wants. **(2)** `rm -i` doesn't work on directories, which the OP specifically asks about. **(3)** As @slhck says, quoting of `$f`, *especially* considering that the OP's very problem is exotic characters in the names.